# How to share vb.net .exe from one system another system(min 6 systems)

Tags: vb.net

I developed Vb.net project.
My project name is Lone.
My front-end is Vb.net Backend is Ms Access.
I completed my project.
Now I copy the Lone.exe and put shortcut into my system desktop.

Now I want to run that Lone.exe to all system.
I don’t no how to share that one.
Tell me how I want to run my project to all system.

Note: In my system only having Vb.net.
Remaining systems doesn’t installed vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the correct version of the .Net framework on all 6 systems, you don't need the whole VB.Net development environment, just the framework. This might already have been installed using Windows Update or similar, so this step might not be needed.

Just try googling *download .net framework x.x* where x.x is the version you need and you should find a link to download the correct version from Microsoft if needed.

After that just copy that executable to each system and run it.